# Create popup after customer logged in

Tags: javascript, magento2.4, popup

How to show a popup as soon as customer logs in.  I created an customer_login event and called an observer, I want to display a phtml file with my popup code.  Following doesn't work

> etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer name="customer_login_observer" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CustomerLogin" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Observer/CustomerLogin.php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
//use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;


class CustomerLogin implements ObserverInterface
{
    
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        
        //code to call phtml file that modal popup
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Observer file you can call the custom template file like this

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
//use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;


class CustomerLogin implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $layout;
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Layout $layout
    ) {
        $this->layout = $layout;
    }
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        
        //code to call phtml file that modal popup
         $block = $this->layout->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Category')->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::customer/loginpopup.phtml')->toHtml();
         return $block;
    }
}
```

**In the above code, you can set block class as per requirement and set template in that.**

Now, you can create template file in the path

**Vendor/Module/view/templates/customer/loginpopup.phtml**

```
<div id="your_popup_container" style="display:none">

    <div class="block block-customer-login" id="popup-modal" >
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong id="block-customer-login-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Registered Customers')) ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content" aria-labelledby="block-customer-login-heading">
        <span>Thank you for login</span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                'type': 'popup',
                'title': 'Thank you',
                'modalClass': 'your_popup_custom_class',
                'responsive': true,
                'innerScroll': true,
                'buttons': [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Back'),
                    class: 'back_button_class',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                        // any javascript coode
                    }
                }]
            };

            $(document).ready(function(){
                var popup = modal(options, $('#your_popup_container')); 
                $("#your_popup_container").modal("openModal");
            });
        }
    );
</script>
```

I have added script code in phtml only, so you don't need to set js in other file.
Please upvote the answer if its useful.